# how do i perform load data on swipe from top as well as bottom in ListView

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I want to load old data when I swipe top and load new data when swipe bottom. How do I perform this functionality? Please help me out to perform this operation.

Comment: check [pullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh)

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of libraries available for doing that pull to refresh stuff.

For example have a look here, https://github.com/OrangeGangsters/SwipyRefreshLayout

To achieve your goal simply detect when the user has pulled down the screen and fetch some data back to your screen. See how,

```
mSwipyRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipyRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh(SwipyRefreshLayoutDirection direction) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Refresh triggered at "
                    + (direction == SwipyRefreshLayoutDirection.TOP ? "top" : "bottom"));
            }
});
```